# How to clear all content of a google worksheet?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am updating a google spreadsheet with python and gspread. I am using a CSV file for source using "values_update":

```
    projectSheet.values_update(
    worksheetName, params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'},
    body={'values': list(csv.reader(open(csvName, encoding='utf-8')))}
)
```

I would like to clear all content of an existing worksheet before updating the new data. 
I couldn’t find a straightforward method of doing that.
Is there a nice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to put the values after the contents of all cells on the worksheet was cleared.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with Python.
- You have already been able to put and get values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

In this answer, the contents of all cells on the worksheet is cleared using the method of `batch_update` of gspread and the values are put to the cleared worksheet.

#### Sample script:

```
# Clear the contents of all cells on the worksheet of "worksheetName".
sheetId = projectSheet.worksheet(worksheetName)._properties['sheetId']
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "deleteRange": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId
                },
                "shiftDimension": "ROWS"
            }
        }
    ]
}
projectSheet.batch_update(body)

projectSheet.values_update(
    worksheetName,
    params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'},
    body={'values': list(csv.reader(open(csvName, encoding='utf-8')))}
)
```

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [DeleteRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deleterangerequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for

Comment: @Iddos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution didn't work for me but using the `clear` method did. So something like `projectSheet.clear()` then go ahead and perform the bulk update.
Here is the link to the `clear` method https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.clear